# Parsing anchor tag and tbody with ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, xpath, elementtree

This is with reference to - [Iterate over python dictionary to retrieve only required rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689327/iterate-over-python-dictionary-to-retreive-only-required-rows)

My HTML is being formatted by external application as below - 
When I process this HTML input with below code

```
        from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

        s = """<table class="darshan" style="width: 290px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="background-color: #efefef; width: 55px;">Release</th>
            <th style="background-color: #efefef; width: 63px;">REFDB</th>
            <th style="background-color: #efefef; width: 151px;">URL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 55px;">3.7.3</td>
            <td style="width: 63px;">
                <p>12345</p>
                <p>232323</p>
                <p>4343454</p>
                <p>5454554</p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 151px;">
                <p><a class="jive-link-external-small" href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">http://google.com</a>
                </p>
                <p><a class="jive-link-external-small" href="http://test12213.com" rel="nofollow">http://test12213.com</a>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 55px;">3.7.4</td>
            <td style="width: 63px;">
                <p>456789</p>
                <p>54545</p>
                <p>5454545</p>
                <p>545454</p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 151px;"><a class="jive-link-external-small" href="http://foo.com" rel="nofollow">http://foo.com</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
        """
        def find_version(ver):
            table = ET.XML(s)
            rows = iter(table)
            headers = [col.text for col in next(rows)]
            for row in rows:
                values = [col.text for col in row]
                out = dict(zip(headers, values))
                if out['Release'] == ver:
                    return out

            return None

        res = find_version('3.7.3')
        if res:
            for x in res.items():
                print(' - '.join(x))
        else:
            print ('Version not found')
```

I get below output:

```
trs: [<Element 'th' at 0x0431CDE0>, <Element 'th' at 0x0431CE40>, <Element 'th' at 0x0431CEA0>]
ths: []
tds: []
out: OrderedDict()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_html.py", line 141, in <module>
    res = find_version(ver)
  File "parse_html.py", line 136, in find_version
    if out['Release'] == ver:
KeyError: 'Release'
```

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables. It helps to find mistake.

Comment: @furas - I have updated the HTML as per your request in original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without comment - see code and `print()` results.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

s = '''<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Release</th>
            <th>REFDB</th>
            <th>URL</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3.7.3</td>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td><a class="jive-link-external-small" href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">http://google.com</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3.7.4</td>
            <td>456789</td>
            <td><a class="jive-link-external-small" href="http://foo.com" rel="nofollow">http://foo.com</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>'''

# --- functions ---

def find_version(ver):
    table = ET.XML(s)

    #rows = iter(table)
    #trs = list(next(rows))
    trs = table.getchildren()[0].getchildren()
    print('trs:', trs)

    #ths = [th.text for th in iter(trs[0])]
    ths = [th.text for th in trs[0].getchildren()]
    print('ths:', ths)

    for tr in trs[1:]:
        tds = []
        #for col in iter(tr):
        for col in tr.getchildren():
            text = " ".join(col.itertext()).strip()
            tds.append(text)
        print('tds:', tds)

        out = dict(zip(ths, tds))
        print('out:', out)

        if out['Release'] == ver:
            return out

# --- main ---

res = find_version('3.7.3')

if res:
    for key, val in res.items():
        print(key, '-', val)
else:
    print ('Version not found')
```

Result

```
trs: [<Element 'tr' at 0x7f26d73005e8>, <Element 'tr' at 0x7f26d7300e08>, <Element 'tr' at 0x7f26d7300868>]
ths: ['Release', 'REFDB', 'URL']
tds: ['3.7.3', '12345', 'http://google.com']
out: {'URL': 'http://google.com', 'REFDB': '12345', 'Release': '3.7.3'}
URL - http://google.com
REFDB - 12345
Release - 3.7.3
```

---

**EDIT:** Version for new HTML.

I skiped `getchildren()` but it works the same way using only indexes. And it's shorter. But it's more readable using `findall()`

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

s = '''<table class="darshan" style="width: 290px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="background-color: #efefef; width: 55px;">Release</th>
            <th style="background-color: #efefef; width: 63px;">REFDB</th>
            <th style="background-color: #efefef; width: 151px;">URL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 55px;">3.7.3</td>
            <td style="width: 63px;">
                <p>12345</p>
                <p>232323</p>
                <p>4343454</p>
                <p>5454554</p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 151px;">
                <p><a class="jive-link-external-small" href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">http://google.com</a>
                </p>
                <p><a class="jive-link-external-small" href="http://test12213.com" rel="nofollow">http://test12213.com</a>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 55px;">3.7.4</td>
            <td style="width: 63px;">
                <p>456789</p>
                <p>54545</p>
                <p>5454545</p>
                <p>545454</p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 151px;"><a class="jive-link-external-small" href="http://foo.com" rel="nofollow">http://foo.com</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>'''

# --- functions ---

def find_version(ver):
    table = ET.XML(s)

    # headers
    #ths = [th.text for th in table[0][0]]
    ths = [th.text for th in table.findall('.//th')]
    #print('ths:', ths)

    # rows
    #for tr in table[1]:
    for tr in table.findall('.//tbody/tr'):
        data = []

        # first col
        data.append(tr[0].text)

        # second col
        data.append([x.text for x in tr[1]])

        # third col
        temp = []
        for x in tr[2]:
            if x.tag == 'a':
                temp.append(x.text)
            else:
                temp.append(x[0].text)
        data.append(temp)

        #print('data:', data)

        # dictionary
        out = dict(zip(ths, data))
        #print('out:', out)

        if out['Release'] == ver:
            return out

# --- main ---

res = find_version('3.7.3')

if res:
    for key, val in res.items():
        print(key, '-', val)
else:
    print ('Version not found')
```

Result

```
Release - 3.7.3
REFDB - ['12345', '232323', '4343454', '5454554']
URL - ['http://google.com', 'http://test12213.com']
```

Comment: The above code works perfectly for the given HTML, whereas I am getting the HTML with additional tags inserted in it as below
<table class="darshan" style="width: 290px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="background-color: #efefef; width: 55px;">Release</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td   </td>
            <td 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Comment: add this html to question (and format). It will be more readable.

Comment: Updated the HTML in original question and your solution as well

Answer (score 0):

I put your input data in "data.xml" in the same folder, then you could try the following code, it works in my computer (It doesn't have enough exception check, but it should be enough to show the right way)

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET                                      

filename = "data.xml"                                                        
tree = ET.ElementTree(file=filename)                                         

def find_version(ver, tree):                                                 
    table = tree.getroot()                                               
    print table                                                          
    headers = []                                                         
    for tbody in table:                                                  
            for tr in tbody:                                             
                    values = []
                    value_flag = True                                    
                    for elem in tr.iter():                               
                            if elem.tag == 'th':                         
                                    headers.append(elem.text)            
                                    value_flag = False                   
                            elif elem.tag == 'td':                       
                                    if not elem.text:
                                            values.append(elem[0].text)  
                                    else:                                
                                            values.append(elem.text)     
                    if value_flag:                                       
                            out = dict(zip(headers, values))             
                            if out['Release'] == ver:
                                    return out

res = find_version('3.7.3', tree)
if res:
    print res
    for x in res.items():
            print(' - '.join(x))
else:
    print ('Version not found')
```

Output:

```
Release - 3.7.3
URL - http://google.com
REFDB - 12345
```

~